# ASP.NET MVC javascript function undefined SignalR

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Ok so it's my first use of SignalR and I was able to make everything work with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) tutorial.

My problem now is that I want to call my server function with a javascript function that doesn't require a button click like in the tutorial. When I try it as the following I get a "function not defined" error.

```
$(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
        var refresh = $.connection.refreshHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back.
        refresh.client.refreshPage = function () {
            // Refresh page
            location.reload();
        };     
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            function rafraichir() {
                // Call the Refresh method on the hub. 
                refresh.server.refresh();
            };
        });
});

function augmenterPriorite(ordre, prio) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AugmenterPriorite", "Home", new { area = "Qualite" })',
        data: { of: ordre, priorite: prio },
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            rafraichir(); //FUNCTION UNDEFINED PROBLEM
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your `rafraichir()` function isn't defined at the right scope. This is basic JavaScript, doesn't have anything to do with SignalR. Make it a function just like `augmenterPriorite`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the thing is I need the "refresh" variable to be defined and when I put "rafraichir" outside of the scope I don't get access to it. (I've updated code to show it)

Comment: Looks like in your success function you should be calling `refresh.client.refreshPage()` instead of `refraichir()`

Comment: To augment the answer by @mason: make it a *global* function just like `augmenterPriorite`. In other words, don't define it inside another function (or 2 functions deep, for that matter), define it at page (window) level.

Comment: Making `refresh` variable global (by removing `var`) and defining `rafraichir()` in the same scope as `augmenterPriorite()` like @mason said did the trick! Thank you guys for your time

Comment: How can I close this question if the answer that helped me is a comment? Should I just delete it?

Comment: No. Feel free to write an actual answer. After some time, you can mark it as the accepted answer. It's common courtesy to allow someone that significantly helped you in the comments to have the opportunity to write the answer themselves, but in this case I'm not really interested.